# How to use TensorFlow freeze_graph util?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained small model and saved graph with `tf.train.write_graph`.  Now I have checkpoint files and `.pbtxt` file. 
I tried to create frozen graph with

```
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph='freeze/Model.pbtxt',
              input_saver="",
              input_binary=False,
              input_checkpoint='freeze/Model.ckpt',
              output_node_names="conv2d/BiasAdd",
              restore_op_name="save/restore_all",
              filename_tensor_name='',
              output_graph='frozenModel.pb',
              clear_devices=True,
                          initializer_nodes=''
              )
```

But it throws `IndexError: list index out of range` in line initializer_nodes=''.

If I remove this line it throws `TypeError: freeze_graph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'initializer_nodes'.`

I wasn't able to find any meaningful explanation about `freeze_graph` parameters. How to fix this error? What values to pass in `freeze_graph` and particularly `initializer_nodes`?